# How to escape Jest watchman when run with husky?

Tags: npm, jestjs, command-line-interface, husky

Hi i'm trying to integrate husky into my process and i can't find a way to make it work with Jest watchman.

My setup:

On root level
`.husky/pre-push`

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npm run test
```

On `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "cd packages/frontend && node scripts/test.js --watchAll",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
```

Now i run `git push` and husky does work by running `npm run test` but i can't exit the cli.
[image]

I've been searching google and most people seem to config husky in `package.json` instead of a `husky` directory but the [official docs](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=install) does this way.

Any idea how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to disable `watchAll` (interactive mode).

```sh
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npm run test -- --watchAll=false
```

## The issue

Running jest will start an *interactive mode* waiting for a user input, therefor it does not `exit` once completed. If this is a script you run locally you need to manually specify that it should run and then exit.

Note that you do not have to add this if the tests are going to be run by `circleci` for example because this is done automatically in CI environments.

[Documentation for `watchAll`](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--watchall)

Comment: Thanks, it works but could you explain me the reason why?